# Highcharts doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So I am trying to use the HighCharts.js library to create a chart.  Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: { renderTo: 'container', type: 'bar' },
            title: { text: 'Fruit Consumption'},
            xAxis: { categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges'] },
            yAxis: { title: { text: 'Fruit eaten'} },
            series: [ {name: 'Jane', data: [1, 0, 4] }, { name: 'John', data: [5, 7, 3]} ]
        });
    });​
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to run this in my browser, and nothing happens.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Your stylesheet looks like it is linking to a Javascript file

Comment: Try to open the development console (F12 for IE >= 9 and Chrome, `Web Developer -> Web console` for Firefox) and see if you see any errors.

Comment: Ok.  I fixed all the errors you brought up, and opened up the developer console.  It says this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: It says this on line 14

Comment: Well I am looking at the source code through the source console and it keeps appending these characters on line 14: â€‹.  I don't have these characters in my code, but it keeps showing up in my source code(when i view the source from browser) when I try to run it.

Comment: The problem is indeed in that extra character. Is that code from jsFiddle copied? Just remove last (whole) line with: `});` and then add manually these three signs.

Answer (score 1):

This is straight from the HighCharts demo page.

Alex W is right that you're referencing the theme incorrectly it is optional. The theme is actually a JS file but you need to use the Script syntax.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
```

I'd check your console to make sure you're loading all the scripts correctly. You're path might be wrong to the highcharts.js file.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me to but i solved using this:

```
#### This code is HighChart image ####
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

##### To show High Chart Code ####
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If this doesn't work try to save jquery.min.js , highchart.js and exporting.js in files.

If you need more help here try this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983869/issue-having-blank-graphic-in-highchart-script
```